# web.xml custom error page not working

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, custom-error-pages

I'm working in Eclipse+tomcat. My custom made static error page is not showing up in tomcat when i click on url for non-existing pages. generated-error.html has a simple img src="404_man.jpg" tag. But I keep getting the error page shown on the pic.

[image]

My servlet version is 3.0 if i view it from manifest.mf. I think it's the right document to look for Servlet version?

[image]
Pls don't leave me hanging...

Comment: Are you sure you're using Servlet version 3.0?

Comment: It doesn't work even if i add <error-code>404</error-code>

Comment: Also, try with several browsers. IIRC, some browsers don't care about the error page: when they receive a 404 status, they show their own error message and disregard the contents of the response.

Comment: my default internal browser is chrome, i changed to firefox, but see no difference there.

Comment: Don't use the default browser, copy your url and pest

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `error code` or `exception-type` tags in web.xml for particular error...

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Answer (score 4):

Before servlet version 3.0 you'll have to specify an error code using the `error-code` tag. It is not required since 3.0. Check if you really use this version. Your `web-app` tag should look like:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0">
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems Internet Explorer issue. Try disabling the option - "Show friendly HTTP error messages" in "Advanced" tab of "Internet Options".

Answer (score 1):

In your error page you have to add isErrorPage="true".

Answer (score 1):

If you want static error page, Than you need to do:

1.include similar to below given example in web.xml file:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error-404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

2. in static error file (i.e. error-404.jsp) add "isErrorPage="true" in  page-dependent attributes. See example:

> ```
> <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
>     pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" isErrorPage="true"%>
> ```

3. Try firefox or chrome. Many times it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, I added `<exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>`, deployed tomcat, deleted exception type back, restarted tomcat with no `<error-code>` line, and it worked. still no idea what was the reason behind the problem that cost me one whole day.

**EDIT:** Restart again, and now it doesn't work...

I restarted again, but still doesn't work, is this a cache problem? it's definitely something that i have no idea of...

Comment: Thatz what i told you earlier in my answer.. It seems that you got some exception from server side code....

Answer (score 0):

Try from another browser, instead of internal eclipse browser. 
And make sure error.jsp is on same level as **web-inf** folder.

Answer (score -3):

For all of you looking for a simple straight forward solution

Please do the following .

1) try running in firefox

2) try running in chrome

root cause : The root cause is internet explorer , since eclipse takes

IE as default browser you keep getting http error . please do as I said

It will work for you . if you like my solution do comment on it : )